# Make a child occupy 100% of its parent when the parent height is undefined

Tags: css, css-float

I have a parent container, `<DIV>`, and two child containers `<p>` and `<a>`.

I have applied a float to `<p>` to make `<a>` & `<p>` appear on one line.

I have applied padding to `<a>` which causes `<DIV>` to expand in height. I would now like to make `<P>` occupy 100% of the height of `<DIV>`. How can I do this?

I know it would work if I assigned a specific height to `<DIV>` and then set `<p>` to height: 100%. However, I am trying to make my CSS code re-useable and don't want to hard code heights.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/nLX75/1/).

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nLX75/2/

Comment: @ExplosionPills, that's nice didn't know that trick, don't you have a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, that's really handy, but is there any way to vertically center the text in the red box. Also, please could you post your fiddle as an Answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not apply `float` to `<p>` to make it appear on one line with the `div`. Use `display: inline-block` instead.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLX75/5/

`float`ing elements are taken out of the document flow. Therefore they "don't know" about the height of their parents anymore. So you can't really rely on layout properties of a `float`ing element's parents to style it properly.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! However, the red background of P, doesn't fill DIV. Is there anyway to do this?